# Different property value is displayed when JavaScript object is expanded in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime

I'm doing some JavaScript debugging with Chrome dev tools and found the following oddity.

How is it possible that `date` has a different value when the  object is expanded?

[image]

Comment: Can you show how the object is created? When I create an object with a date it shows the same value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be careful with chrome console when printing objects. Please note that chrome does evaluations when printing / expanding objects as well as it does it asynchronously (meaning other code may execute in the meantime and change the object). Always try to print to String for debugging, rather than printing the object itself.

I made a very simple example to illustrate the problem.

```
<div id="foo"></div>

console.log($('#foo')); //expected output [div#foo...]
$('#foo').attr('id','hello');
```

The actual output in the chrome console is:

[image: example image]

[Try it yourself here (JSFiddle).](https://jsfiddle.net/d326Ldrp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you define a non enumerable property on an object like this

```
Object.defineProperty(res, 'url', { value: '/api/url' });
```

To fix this you have to make it enumerable like this

```
Object.defineProperty(res, 'url', { value: '/api/url', enumerable: true });
```