# Array length incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array filled with objects. It contains 23 items in total, however when I perform a .length on it, it returns 20.

```
// Get the new routes
var array = PostStore.getPostList();

console.log(array.objects);
console.log(array.objects.length);
```

Image of what my console returns:

[image: Array Length]

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Is `getPostList` returning a `promise`?

Comment: Can you post `PostStore` data?

Comment: Do you modify `array.objects` before you look at the console? The console is "live" so it shows the current value of the array, not what it contained when you called `console.log()`.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31426530/5020253) about chrome console logging.

Comment: Exactly not sure what is wrong. But you can try Clear history after restart the browser. Also choose `Disable Cache (when devtools is opened) in Browser Console -> Settings.

Comment: @RJK: That's not going to help.

Comment: The only thing PostStore does is returning an object which includes this array.

Comment: I did not modify the array in anyway before logging it. The way it's shown in the code above is precisely how it looks in my code.

Comment: @Timon we're reffering to modifications **after** logging

Comment: @DenysSéguret Ah no, I'm not modifying anything yet. Just logging it. :)

Comment: Are you sure it's not modified at the source ? Anyway, just try what I suggest and you'll see.

Comment: You are correct. I think the array is being changed between the time I logged it and the time I opened it. Your solution seems to work. Marking it as an answer in a min. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is probably that the array changed between the time you logged it and the time you opened it in the console.

To get the array at the logging time, clone it:

```
console.log(array.objects.slice());
console.log(array.objects.length);
```

Note that this won't protect against the array element properties changing. If you want to freeze them too, you need a deep cloning, which is most often possible with

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array.objects.slice()));
```

This won't work if the objects aren't stringifyable, though (cyclic objects, very deep objects, properties throwing exceptions at reading, etc.). In that case you'll need a specific cloning, like my own [JSON.prune.log](https://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune).

A alternative to logging is also, in such a case, to debug. Set a breakpoint and look at the objects while the code is stopped.

Comment: While this probably is the case, its funny iv'e never ran into this issue before, I would ask is this a chrome condition or infact if you're using the array obj on 2 consecutive lines will it cause issues ?

Comment: Instead of doing all that cloning and slicing just print `.toString()`

Comment: @StoyanDekov But then you'll be unable to see everything

Comment: @Pogrindis All browsers are subject to this problem. The reason is they can't build a deep cloned representation of what you log because it would be much too heavy.