# How to get count object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I have a problem, I learning Babylonjs and i try get lenght scene.meshes, but `scene.meshes.length` and `Object.keys(scene.meshes).length`

[image]

Comment: Please may you replace the image with text? We can't copy/paste code or objects from images.

Comment: Can you share ur code snippet?

Comment: The length changes because Chrome shows the current state of the object. This means that it changed in the time you logged it and the time you opened it. See [array length incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606226/array-length-incorrect)

Comment: I tried console.log(scene.meshes.length); and console.log(Object.keys(scene.meshes).length);

Comment: Reyno, sure you are right, thank you!