# offsetTop returns the wrong value

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to get the offsetTop of an alement that does not have an ID so I am getting the selectors by name:

```
const element = document.getElementsByTagName('bs-datepicker-container');
```

and then if I where to console.log `element` I can see the offset top is -55 which is correct, the element is off the screen by approximately 55 pixels.

however when I specifically target the element as follows:

```
console.log(element['0'].offsetTop);
```

I suddenly see an output of 949. considering my screen size is 1080 this would mean the offsetTop was almost at the bottom of my screen which it is not.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Perhaps this is why the values differ? [Different property value is displayed when JavaScript object is expanded in Chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425320/different-property-value-is-displayed-when-javascript-object-is-expanded-in-chro) (also true of other browsers)

Comment: Did you find a solution !?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in Angular. When calling `element.offsetTop` within `ngOnInit()` it returned completely different (and wrong) values.

I solved it by calling it in `ngAfterViewChecked()`. This method is called last in the component lifecycle (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).
It seems like `offsetTop` only works after the view is completely initialized.