# weird string value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

i'm working on Angular and i just met this weird thing, maybe someone can explain me this dark magic thing :

```
  console.log('coordinates', coordinates[30])
  console.log('typeof x', typeof coordinates[30].x)
  console.log('typeof y', typeof coordinates[30].y)
  console.log('y', coordinates[30].y)
  console.log('y.value', coordinates[30].y.value)
```

and the result in chrome console is

```
coordinates {x: "13.69", y: "0"}
                  x: "13.69"
                  y: {value: "6.16"}
                  __proto__: Object
typeof x string
typeof y string
y 0
y.value undefined
```

[result screenshot in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS5QZ.png)
[result screenshot in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm8iH.png)

the coordinates array results from a D3 json import and the 6.16 value seems to come from a previous entry of the array, i don't understand how.

Edit:
I don't understand why the typeof return string and not Object ?

Thank you

Comment: which part is mysterious?

Comment: Where you find the coordinates it doesn't make them float. So you have to parse them as float like ```parseFloat(coordinates[30].x)```

Comment: Before log an object in console try use JSON.stringify(), is a clearer way to inspect the content of an object

Comment: He's talking about the value of y.  It shows as y: "0", which is the current value.  Clicking the expansion arrow, it shows y: {value: "6.16"}, which is a previous value before it was updated.  He's asking how that's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different property value is displayed when JavaScript object is expanded in Chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425320/different-property-value-is-displayed-when-javascript-object-is-expanded-in-chro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of your console log, the value of y is "0". Therefore, the typeof call returns "string". When you later on expand the coordinates object in the console, it fetches its current value. At that point, the value of y is {value: "6.16"}. If you were to log the typeof of y at that point, it would return "object". Here's a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/gaqbtovk/

```
const coordinates = {y: "0"};
console.log(coordinates); // shows the updated value on expand, {value: "6.16"}
console.log(typeof coordinates.y); // string

coordinates.y = {value: "6.16"};
console.log(typeof coordinates.y); // object
```