# Why the JSON's are different in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have written some code and I am printing to console . A very strange thing is happening .Below the screenshot attached :
[image: Printed json object(unexpanded)]

[image: Printed json object(expanded)]

There are two screenshot attached and in both the screenshots the attribute canvasWidth is showing some strange values. When it is unexpanded it is showing `287`(expected) and when it is expanded it is showing `5`.

But when I am adding the debug points then it is showing the correct value . Does anyone have any idea why it is showing this strange behaviour ???

Thanks

Comment: It gets evaluated when it prints to console, and evaluated again once you click on expand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different property value is displayed when JavaScript object is expanded in Chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425320/different-property-value-is-displayed-when-javascript-object-is-expanded-in-chro)

Answer (score 3):

Chrome's debugging tools will re-evaluate the object when you click to expand, so the expanded version shows what the object looks like at the time of the click, not at the time of the console.log. Apparently, the value changed in between when the console.log happened and when the click happened.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably changing this object in your code, the first log is done instantly, right when you call `console.log`, but your object was mutated before you had the time to expand it.

To make sure the object logged is not mutated you can copy it before the log:

```js
// not sure of your actual log code but:
console.log('==>', index, {...object})
// instead of just
console.log('==>', index, object)
```

Comment: It is only 1 level deep copy - Shallow Copy.

Comment: yeah, his `canvasWidth` property was at the first level

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```js
const obj = { cnt: 0 };

console.log(obj);

(function loop() {
  obj.cnt++;
  setTimeout(loop, 50);
})();
```

It may be useful to understand what just happend:

[image]

It is worth to remember that JavaScript is asynchronous.