# How do I interpret this GET request?

Tags: angular, typescript, get

I have an Angular application that uses a service to send GET requests to retrieve data from a MongoDB database. One of the methods searches for a custom object called an Estimate with the following properties:

Estimate.model.ts:

```
export class Estimate {
    constructor(
        public storyNumber: string,
        public assumptions?: string,
        public risks?: string,
        public estimateDate?: string ) { }
}
```

The service itself is called the ToolboxRepositoryService and the method is called `getStoryEstimate()`:

```
export class ToolboxRepositoryService {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/"; 
  };

 getStoryEstimate(storyNumber: string) {
    return this.http.get<Estimate>(this.baseUrl + "spestoryestimate/story/" + storyNumber);
  }
}
```

Currently, my database holds 2 records of the object type, Estimate, with story numbers  9999 and 9998. I can test the GET requests using Postman and the records are returned as intended. However, when I execute the same GET request in my application I get a different set of results.

The relevant component methods are described below:

```
getStoryEstimate(storyNumber: string){
    console.log('Retrieving estimate...')
    this.toolboxRepository.getStoryEstimate(storyNumber).subscribe((estimate: Estimate) => {
      if(estimate.storyNumber){
        this.storyEstimate.assumptions = estimate.assumptions;
        this.storyEstimate.estimateDate = estimate.estimateDate;
        this.storyEstimate.risks = estimate.risks;
        this.storyEstimate.storyNumber = estimate.storyNumber;
      }
      else {
        console.log('Error: story number not found!')
      }
    })
  }

  findStoryEstimate(storyNumber: string){
    this.getStoryEstimate(storyNumber);
    console.log(this.storyEstimate)
  }
```

The problem arises when I request an Estimate with the story number 9999, whereby the console returns an Estimate object with undefined properties. What's more, is that the object appears to contain a JSON object with all the relevant attributes of the
[Estimate in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8fR4.png).

How do I interpret this result? Alternatively, is there a way I could access the JSON object's attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.toolboxRepository.getStoreEstimate` is an asynchronous call. Where you're `console.log(this.storeEstimate)` is the data won't be returned. Toss a log into the subscribe and you'll see that the order is executed differently.

Comment: I understand, but my main question is regarding the screenshot. Why does is there an Estimate object with null properties yet it contains the relevant information within the call itself?

Comment: Because that's a reference object, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425320/different-property-value-is-displayed-when-javascript-object-is-expanded-in-chro